# In which direction to open AD Connect ports?

Tags: active-directory, firewall, azure, entra-id

Practising setting up SSPR in my Azure lab and struggling with which ports to open on the AD Connect server. I've found the list of firewall ports to open on Microsoft docs but as a beginner I'm not sure where and in which direction to open the ports:

```
1. Do I need to open the ports on the AD connect server?
2. Should I open them inbound, outbound or in both direction?
```

Environment: 1 DC - 1 AD Connect server. Both are deployed on VMs in Azure

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the list of firewall ports you mentioned is like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-ports). If you just imitate your on-premise environment on the Azure VM. I think you can follow on-premise Hybrid Identity configuration on the Azure VM environment.

> 1. Do I need to open the ports on the AD connect server?

Yes, you should open the ports as the table1&table2 lists in the firewall on the AD connect server and DC.

> 2. Should I open them inbound, outbound or in both direction?

Yes, you should open the ports in the Table2 & Table6b lists for the inbound direction of Vnet for the communication between the Azure AD Connect server and Azure AD. Default, It allows any traffics to be directed to Vnet or Internet in the outbound directory, you can keep no change.

Comment: please let me know if this reply helps.